# HTML5 and @font-face with IE

Tags: javascript, html, fonts, css, font-face

I've been trying to get @font-face to render for the last 2 hours using a kit from font-squirrel. Check out [this link](http://raul.tinygiantstudios.co.uk/) and you'll see that in all non-IE browsers everything is peachy, but in IE it fails to render entirely...

Here's my font-face code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CartoGothicStdBook';
    src: url('../cartogothicstd-book-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../cartogothicstd-book-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../cartogothicstd-book-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../cartogothicstd-book-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../cartogothicstd-book-webfont.svg#cartogothicstdbook') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

What am I missing? The fonts are in the root directory, as well as the stylesheet (although I don't think it makes a difference). Is it because HTML5 tags (I'm using HTML5 shiv) can't use @font-face pre-IE9?

Hope to hear from the jedi-coders out there soon,

Comment: What tags are you using it on?

Comment: Heading tags which is located within the new section tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the polyfill - modernizer2.js from http://www.modernizr.com/ instead of the html5 shiv.
@font-face is a css feature that is detected by Modernizer see http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#features-css

Comment: Hey Leonie, how would modernizr help implementing @font-face rules? As far as I know modernizr determines support for an element, where as font-face has been accepted by IE since version 4?